# How to register global keyboard shortcuts in Flutter desktop application?

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to register global keyboard shortcuts (the ones that work even if your app is not in focus) within Flutter desktop application.
Could not to find any related info on this topic.

Any hints appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter doesn't provide any mechanism for registering shortcuts outside the scope of your application. You would need to use [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to do the registration with platform-specific code, and then to invoke a method on the Dart side when the shortcut is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that allows you to register a global shortcut

Global Shortcuts: https://pub.dev/packages/global_shortcuts

The name should be Global Shortcut though, as it allows registering only 1 shortcut.